# Run SpecFlow tests in build of tfs

Tags: msbuild, specflow

I created tests by spec flow . I need my build will run the test (Automated Test) .
It is possibility ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this should just work. Specflow generates unit tests as part of the build, so if you just tell the build to run all the tests in the test dll, then it should run all of your specflow tests